# Steamwritter Write group of data

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a code but it's not grouping multiple data.

The file is also included as an image below: StudentInfo.txt

My code is:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim CN As New String(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CON").ToString)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Private Async Sub Studentdata()
        Try
            Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from students", CN)
                dt.Clear()
                Await Task.Run(Sub() da.Fill(dt))
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Studentdata()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim Classroom = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row("Class"))
        Dim section = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row("Section"))
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Local.txt"))
            For Each grp In Classroom
                sw.WriteLine(vbNewLine)
                sw.WriteLine("Class :" & grp.Key)
                sw.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------")
                sw.WriteLine("Student Id".PadLeft(0) & "Student Name".PadLeft(15) & "Section".PadLeft(25))
                sw.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------")
                For Each line In grp
                    'For Each sec In section

                    'Next
                    sw.WriteLine(line(0).ToString.PadRight(13) & line(1).ToString.PadRight(31) & line(3))
                    sw.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------")
                Next
            Next
        End Using
        Process.Start(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Local.txt"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

I have multiple groups same result but its repeating each row data[text] multiple times

The data and requested format as like below

--Current Result

Comment: You made a group-by-section view of the data, but then didn't do anything with it.  Right now, you're asking for a grouping by class, and that's exactly what you're getting.  You probably need to group by both class and section.

Comment: Maybe you need to group by section inside the `For Each grp In Classroom`.